# Dependent sum and equality with Coq

Tags: coq

I have types `B` and `A n` where `n:nat`.  I want to prove that `B` is the sum of all `A n`. I have three functions

```
foo (n:nat) (a: A n) : B
rang (b:B) : nat
bar (b:B) : A (rang b)
```

I can prove

```
forall (b:B), foo (rang b) (bar b) = b
forall (n:nat) (a: A n),  rang (foo n a) = n
```

But when I write the theorem

```
forall (n:nat) (a: A n), bar (foo n a) = a
```

I get "The term `bar (foo n a)`  has type `A (rang (foo n a))` while it is expected to have type `A n`".
What can I do?

Comment: Please post a working piece of code. It is not clear whether `A, `B`, `foo`, `rang` etc. are concrete types or variables. As written, without knowing more about them, you cannot prove the desired equalities. There is information that you are not communicating.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code snippet doesn't work I will assume that you are trying to construct an equality type on dependent types.

```ml
Hypothesis A: nat -> Type.
Hypothesis B: Type.

Definition foo (n: nat) (a: A n) : B.  Admitted.
Definition rang (b: B) : nat. Admitted.
Definition bar (b: B) : A (rang b). Admitted.
```

You now have

```ml
Theorem thm1: forall (b: B), foo (rang b) (bar b) = b.
Proof. Admitted.

Theorem thm2: forall (n: nat) (a: A n),  rang (foo n a) = n.
Proof. Admitted.
```

You have difficulty writing this:

```ml
Theorem thm3: forall (n:nat) (a: A n), bar (foo n a) = a.
```

which gives you the error:

```ml
In environment
n : nat
a : A n
The term "a" has type "A n" while it is expected to have type
"A (rang (foo n a))".
```

Is this what you want? Well, in that case, the root problem is that to construct a type `=` you have to let Coq know that *the types* of two terms must be the same, but since you have wrapped $n$ inside some functions, Coq has no idea whether `rang (foo n a) = n`. You can check how `eq` is constructed:

```ml
Check eq.
eq
     : ?A -> ?A -> Prop
where
?A : [ |- Type]
```

This is checked syntactically, which means propositional equality won't simply work in your case (even though you can prove that `rang (foo n a) = n`). This is also known as heterogenous equality. Also, by checking the recursion rule of `eq` you will know more about this:

```ml
Check eq_rect.
------------------------
eq_rect
     : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type),
P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
```

It says you will obtain a new term of type $ P y $ if you can provide a *proof* which states that $x = y$ holds (this is actually the Leibniz rule). So the trick to type check is using `transport` or type cast as suggested by @djao.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an explicit cast?

```
Theorem rang_foo : ∀ (n:nat) (a: A n), rang (foo n a) = n.
Proof.
  admit.
Admitted.

Definition cast {X Y : nat} (e : X = Y) : A X → A Y :=
  match e with erefl => id end.

Goal ∀ (n:nat) (a: A n), cast (rang_foo n a) (bar (foo n a)) = a.
```

Comment: "The term "id" has type "ID" while it is expected to have type 
"A X -> A Y" (cannot unify "Top.A X" and "Type")."

Comment: Since you didn't post a full working file, I don't know exactly what you did. Here is my file, in which it works: https://gist.github.com/davidjao/b6209fa5242368b80d77c996d7273600

Comment: Probably `erefl` is being seen as a variable name, rather than the alias from SSReflect. `eq_refl` in its place should work.

Comment: @djao Yes, I can write the theorem now, but I can't prove it:)  The function `cast` need `eq_refl` to be simplified. Is each proof `e: X=Y` equal to `eq_refl`?

Comment: In general you need Streicher's axiom K to show that all proofs of equality are equal. When equality is decidable (which is the case for `nat`), you can prove the result directly without axioms. See https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html

Comment: `Theorem eq_proofs_unicity A (eq_dec : forall x y : A, x = y \/ x <> y) (x : A)
: forall (y:A) (p1 p2:x = y), p1 = p2.`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use heterogeneous or "John-Majors" equality.

Essentially, the problem is that you are trying to say that two terms of syntactically different (but equal) types are the same. However, Coq and related systems require that terms are reducible to the same thing, rather than merely equal.

Heterogeneous equality solves this by allowing you to use two different types to set up your equality. You then must prove that both the types and the terms are equal in order to prove the equality.

In Coq, there's an implementation of heterogeneous equality in the standard library: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.JMeq.html. You can then write

```
forall (n : nat) (a : A n), JMeq a (bar (foo n a))
```

just as you wanted. Working with JMeq is a little more difficult, see http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Equality.html for examples.